# python how to abstract the class of member variable

Tags: python, interface, architecture, abstraction

suppose that i have a module like below

```py
class B:
  def ...
  def ...

class A:
  b: B

  def ...
  def ...
```

**I use class B only as member variable of class A**

when i try to abstract this module for my buisness logic, what should i do?

1. one big interface, which has abstract method for class A and class B
2. two interface, which has abstract method for class A and class B individually
3. all above are wrong. another way

Comment: I don't think I understand what problem you are trying to solve, but either way it is off topic for Stack Overflow. This is not the place to ask subjective questions about code design.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i just make a better architecture for my SW. i am beginner at SW design but i have to make real world SW at work right now. so before making decision i wanted to get some advice. i did`t know that i must not ask subjective question about code design at the stackvoverflow. if i bother you, i am sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both, 1 & 2 are correct approach, but it completely depends on your application.

I think, two interfaces, which would have abstract method for class A and class B individually is the right approach when both of your classes have separate workings and are completely different from each other.

But, as you have mentioned in your code that you have inherited class B in class A. If you create a single interface for class A, it will also allow you to access the methods from class B. So, this approach is good. Also, this approach will shorten the length of your code, resulting in fast processing.

I hope this would help you to take your decision. Let me know if any other clarification required.

Comment: thank you for reply. i think 2 seperate interface is proper in this case